# Scripting/headless automation of VSCode?

Tags: automation, visual-studio-code, refactoring

Is there a convenient way to use VSCode "as a library or service," so that I can write scripts/programs that can perform renames and other refactorings, analyze code, etc.?

I know I can reach directly for language-specific solutions, such as using tsserver for Typescript, but VSCode supports many languages, and it does more out of the box (e.g., renames edit the actual files, which tsserver doesn't).

Comment: I once investigated solution for this, but my conclusion was only to create a extension which does some IPC with external process, and do the job. Maybe there might be similar extension which does it in Visual Studio Marketplace.

Comment: @ymonad can you share a link to the extension?